# Restarting urllib connection after error 500 or ignoring it all together

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using urllib for python 3 to create requests every few seconds in a loop. Occasionally, the requests I send receive the following error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

At this point it crashes my script. I do the requests as followed:

```
        ret = urllib.request.urlopen('URL' + command)
        return json.loads(ret.read())
```

Is there a way to work around the error 500 and get the loop to ignore the failed request and move to the next request? I'm fairly new to python and urllib in general, so I apologize if this is too basic of a question.

Answer (score 0):

Learn the `try: ... except ...:` Python structures. The light will come automatically ;)

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ret = urllib.request.urlopen('URL' + command)

return None if ret.getCode() == 500 else json.loads(ret.read())
```